# Programmatic segmented control can't insert

Tags: ios, swift

I've searched everywhere for a solution, but I can't figure out why this doesn't work`

```
listing.termContracts.forEach {
        cell.segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: $0.availableFor, at: cell.segmentedControl.numberOfSegments)
}
```

It returns a strange error of: Cannot invoke 'insertSegment' with an argument list of type '(withTitle: String, at: Int)'

Which makes no sense, because I'm passing in the right data types. The termContracts struct looks like the following:

```
import UIKit

struct TermContract {

var availableFor: String
var availableYear: String
var sharedPrivate: String
var spacesAvailable: Int
var rent: Int
var deposit: Int
var averageUtilities: Int?

init(_ dict: [String: Any]) {
    self.availableFor = dict["availableFor"] as? String ?? ""
    self.availableYear = dict["availableYear"] as? String ?? ""
    self.sharedPrivate = dict["sharedPrivate"] as? String ?? ""
    self.spacesAvailable = dict["spacesAvailable"] as? Int ?? 0
    self.rent = dict["rent"] as? Int ?? 0
    self.deposit = dict["deposit"] as? Int ?? 0
    self.averageUtilities = dict["averageUtilities"] as? Int
}
}
```

is this a glitch?

Comment: You are missing the third argument `animated`, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol/1618588-insertsegment

Comment: `segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: String?, at: Int, animated: Bool)`